# rasterio memoryfile has no attribute profile

Tags: python, merge, rasterio, in-memory

I am trying to write a function in rasterio that has equivalent functionality to a function I wrote in rioxarray.  To avoid creating excessive files to the disk I am trying to use a MemoryFile, however I can't seem to get it behave as a normal file (written to disk) would with regards to it's profile.  I have tried multiple ways of saving the profile (see commented-out section) but get the same error on the merge command:

```
---> mosaic, out_trans = merge(ds)
```

> "AttributeError: 'MemoryFile' object has no attribute 'profile'"
> on line

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import xarray as xr
import rasterio as rio

#%%
from rioxarray import merge
# using xarray/rioxarray
def crop_merge(file_list, shape_file=None, shape_ID=None):
    # for file in file_list open file, crop, and close uncropped file
    cube_dict = {}
    for file in file_list:
        cube = xr.open_dataarray(file,engine='rasterio')
        # mask no data
        cube_masked = cube.where(cube != 0)
        cube.close()
        if shape_file:
            polys = gpd.read_file(shape_file)
            # reproject shapefile
            polys_reproject  = polys.to_crs(crs=cube_masked.rio.crs)
            # find shape
            if shape_ID:
                polys_json_str = polys_reproject[polys_reproject["Name"]==shape_ID].geometry.to_json()
            else:
                polys_json_str = polys_reproject.geometry.to_json()
            # extract geometry
            polys_dict = json.loads(polys_json_str)
            polys_geo = polys_dict['features'][0]['geometry']
            # crop
            cropped_cube = cube_masked.rio.clip([polys_geo], crs=cube_masked.rio.crs)
            cube_masked.close()
            # save to dictionary
            cube_dict[file] = cropped_cube
        else:
            cube_dict[file] = cube_masked
            cube_masked.close()
    # merge cropped files
    ds = list(cube_dict.values())
    merged = merge.merge_arrays(ds, nodata=np.nan)
    return merged

#%%
from rasterio.mask import mask
from rasterio.merge import merge
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
# using only rasterio
def crop_merge(file_list, shape_file=None, shape_ID=None):
    # for file in file_list open file, crop
    cube_dict = {}
    for file in file_list:
        cube_obj = rio.open(file)
        if shape_file:
            polys = gpd.read_file(shape_file)
            # reproject shapefile
            polys_reproject  = polys.to_crs(crs=cube_obj.crs)
            # find shape
            if shape_ID:
                polys_json_str = polys_reproject[polys_reproject["Name"]==shape_ID].geometry.to_json()
            else:
                polys_json_str = polys_reproject.geometry.to_json()
            # extract geometry
            polys_dict = json.loads(polys_json_str)
            polys_geo = polys_dict['features'][0]['geometry']
            # crop
            clipped_cube, clipped_transform = mask(cube_obj, [polys_geo], crop=True)            
            # mask no data
            clipped_cube[clipped_cube==0] = np.nan
            profile = cube_obj.profile
            profile.update(
                height=clipped_cube.shape[0],
                width=clipped_cube.shape[1],
                transform=clipped_transform)
            clipped_out = MemoryFile()
            # clipped_out.open(driver='GTiff',    
            #     height=clipped_cube.shape[1],
            #     width=clipped_cube.shape[2],
            #     count=clipped_cube.shape[0],
            #     dtype=clipped_cube.dtype,
            #     crs=cube_obj.crs,
            #     transform=clipped_transform)
            clipped_out.open(**profile)
            clipped_out.write(clipped_cube)
            cube_dict[file] = clipped_out    
        else:
            cube_dict[file] = cube_obj
    # merge cropped files
    ds = list(cube_dict.values())
    print(ds)
    mosaic, out_trans = merge(ds)
    return mosaic
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS/SE!  Maybe I'm missing it, but it looks like you may not have imported `MemoryFile`.  If you are going to invoke it that way, you would likely need to do `from rasterio.io import MemoryFile`.

Comment: ah yeah I just didn't copy that from the top of my file.  I do import it.  I'll edit my post to reflect that

Comment: See [example](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/memory-files.html#memoryfile-bytesio-meets-namedtemporaryfile). You're not setting the output dataset object from `clipped_out.open(**profile)` to a variable. The `MemoryFile` itself is not a dataset.

Comment: I thought I do set it to a variable when I initialize it as clipped_out = MemoryFile().  I guess I am confused because later when I list the values in my dictionary they are DataArrays as I wanted.  I can't use the "with" lingo in the example, can you be more specific?